# how to swap twice in one tx

Tags: jupiter

just like this transaction: https://solscan.io/tx/2T3jByRBFL5sJ7a9FeZVT4jcJitPKZ7L8DBAU3UmoXLceTSyJKb5Kqi17TvRASuoaqJc3rUMptFGuLb42854K5yA

how does this realize by Jupiter API ? Does anyone know it? Thanks.

I tried to use /swap-instruction method, but failed

[image]